# Where is the jar that contains com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager?

Tags: tcserver

I have a TC server instance that works fine, however, a different instance created from the same template craps out with:
Could not load Logmanager "com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager

and I can't find where the jar that contains it on the instance that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using tc Runtime 7.0.x?  That class is added to the tomcat-juli.jar in the bin directory and the tomcat-juli.jar in the bin/extras directory.

-Jason

Comment: Interesting, when I look conf/tomcat.version it says 8.5.13.B.RELEASE . The deployment must have some sort of bug that got things mixed up. Time to complain to the deployment people. Thanks Jason !